# how can i create a const float*& variable in python c++ wrapper

Tags: python, c++, wrapper

I have already built a python wrapper by swig, but there need to pass a `const *float` variable into c++ function. So how to call this variable? or replace it by python code?

The c++ attributes of get_face_feature is `get_face_feature(const char* image,int img_type,const float* &feature)`
Here is the python function:

```
import face
import numpy as np
a = face.BaiduFaceApi()
a.sdk_init()
feature=[]
b = a.get_face_feature('1.jpg', 2,feature)
print(b)
```

Here is the swig wrapper code:

```
%module face

%{
#include "baidu_face_api.h" 
%}

// %inline %{
//     float *GetReference(BaiduFaceApi *api, const char* image,int 
//img_type)
//     {
//         float *feature;
//         float *&ptr = feature;
//         api->get_face_feature(image, img_type, ptr);
//         return ptr;
//     }
// %}

%include "baidu_face_api.h"
```

Here is the setup function to build the python package:

```
from distutils.core import setup,Extension

pht_module=Extension('_face',
include_dirs=['../../include/'],
library_dirs=['../../facelib/'],
libraries=['BaiduFaceApi-ubuntu16', 'FaceSDK'],
runtime_library_dirs=['../../facelib/'],
sources=['python_wrapper_wrap.cxx'],
extra_compile_args=['-O3', '-std=c++0x', '-fPIC' ],
swig_opts=['-c++'],
)

setup(name='face',
version='0.1',
author='SWIG Docs',
description='Simple wsig pht from docs',
ext_modules=[pht_module],
py_modules=['face']
)
```

I have already tried the typemap and pointer, but without success

Comment: I'm afraid it's completely unclear to me what you're asking about here. We're going to need more detail on what exactly you're trying to achieve, what exactly you have tried so far, and how exactly that has failed…

Comment: @Michael Kenzel I modified, cheers